# Does Azure storage CreateIfNotExist() result in extra round-trip?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Most of the examples on working with Azure Storage have `.CreateIfNotExist();` inside the program flow.
So if I have a method that puts a blob, but before executing the put it executes `.CreateIfNotExist();`, does this mean that there is an extra round-trip being made to the storage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It would be better to create the container when you role starts (WebRole.cs/WorkerRole.cs) or when your application starts (Global.asax.cs)

Comment: hi, i am facing the problem of createifnotexist on blob container, and that cause my application hang sometimes, so i think ur suggestion could be a way to solve the problem. Can you elaborate more on how you going to detect if the container is already created?